# ASP.NET Mvc Generic Controllers and Ninject injection InRequestScope at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

A while ago, I built a ControllerFactory with the goal of use Generic Controllers in my Asp.Net MVC project. This factory is something like this:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        if (/*controller is generic, I know it by a convention in the controllerName*/)
        {
            string typeName = //resolve Type name from controllerName and requestContext;
            Type controllerType = typeof(MyGenericController<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(typeName));

            var ninjecKernel = //get a ninject kernel;
            return (IController)ninjecKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }
        else 
        {
            //build a normal controller
        }
    }
}
```

I use this controller factory in the Globar.asax file like this `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());`

But in the services injected by ninject to the controller are InSingletonScope. Now I decided to inject those services InRequestScope, so, the services can share the same EntityFramework context. To archive this, I'm trying to use [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412383/Dependency-Injection-in-asp-net-mvc4-and-webapi-us) approach, when services are injected in request scope, using the Ninject.Web.Mvc.dll. In this approach ninject is who build the controllers internally by inheriting MvcApplication of Global.asax from NinjectHttpApplication, so I don't know how to keep the Generic Controller code.

How can I archieve both goals?

Answer (score 0):

Don't inherit your Global.asax from NinjectHttpApplication. You will still be able to use `InRequestScope` to control lifetimes.

Comment: Ok, i won't, but that doesn't answer my question